# Transfer Likes from old Page to new Page

Tags: facebook

I sold my business. The new company has a different name. There currently are my Facebook page and the other companies' page. I'd like to move all the likes over to the new company page. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: could you please clarify the question?

Answer (score 4):

From Facebook's help ([ref](https://www.facebook.com/help/249601088403018#Can-I-merge-two-Facebook-Pages?)):

> If you have 2 Facebook Pages for the same thing, you may be able to
>   merge them if:
>
> - You're an admin of both Pages
> - Your Pages have similar names and represent the same thing
> - Your Pages have the same address, if they have physical locations
>
> To merge your Pages:
>
> Go to facebook.com/pages/merge Select 2 Pages you want to merge and
>   click Continue Click Request Merge
>
> If you're unable to merge your Pages, it means that your Pages aren't
>   eligible to be merged. If you see the option to request to merge your
>   Pages, we'll review your request.
>
> If your Pages can be merged, the people who like your Pages and any
>   check-ins will be combined, but posts, photos, reviews, ratings and
>   the username will be deleted from the Page you merge. The Page you
>   want to keep will remain unchanged, except for the addition of people
>   who like the Page and check-ins that were merged from the other Page.
>   The Page you don't want to keep will be removed from Facebook, and you
>   won't be able to unmerge it.

Given those constraints, it may be better for you to simply announce the merger and invite people who like your Page to also like the other Page.